# pynput code doesn't give me a simple string as a key

Tags: python, types, pynput

I have this simple pynput code:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keys = []

def on_press(key):
    keys.append(key)
    write_file(keys)


def write_file(keys):

    allowed = ['7','9','1','3','4','5','6','q','w','e','z']
    with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
        for key in keys:
            if key in allowed:
                # removing ''
                k = str(key).replace("'", "")
                f.write(k)

                f.write(',')

def on_release(key):

    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with Listener(on_press = on_press,
        on_release = on_release) as listener:

    listener.join()
```

When I run this and enter 7 on my keypad, I would expect it to write 7 into log.txt because it is in the allowed list.  But it doesn't.  I traced it using import pdb and pdb.set_trace() and when I manually type in

```
'7' in allowed
```

I get a True

But when I use

```
key in allowed
```

I get a False even though key is '7'.  I suspect it has to do with type because when I use

```
type(key)
```

I get

```
<class 'pynput.keyboard._xorg.KeyCode'>
```

So I'm thinking I have to just make key a normal and boring string.  But

```
str(key)
```

still won't say that it is in the allowed list.

I tried looking at the documentation for pynput regarding KeyCode, but I don't think that is helping me.  Maybe someone else knows how to make this work?

Comment: you have to compare with  `key.char`. But you will get error for keys which don't have `.char` - ie. `Ctrl`, `Alt`, but also `Space` - and you may have to use `try/except`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare

```
key.char == '7'
```

but it gives error when `key` doesn't have `.char` - i.e. `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift`, etc. and even `Space` - so safer is to compare

```
key == KeyCode.from_char('7')
```

---

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, KeyCode


def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('from_char:', key == KeyCode.from_char('7'))
        print('key.char :', key.char == '7')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error:', ex)


def on_release(key):

    #print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, KeyCode


#allowed = [KeyCode.from_char('7'), KeyCode.from_char('9')]
#allowed = [KeyCode.from_char(char) for char in ['7','9','1','3','4','5','6','q','w','e','z']]
allowed = [KeyCode.from_char(char) for char in '7913456qwez']
    
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('allowed:', key in allowed)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error:', ex)


def on_release(key):

    #print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: awesome!  thanks!  Kind of a dumb question but how would one know that Ctrl, Alt and Space don't have a .char?  I mean other than you telling me I don't know how I would have come across that and I don't see it in the pynput documents

Comment: if you try to run code without `try/except` then you will know even without documentation that sometimes it doesn't return `.char` :) But it is rather unusall sitation - objects should rather always have the same fields. And when code raises error then you can try to search in documentation if it is natural behavior and if there is solution for this - or you directly use `try/except` to resolve problem. In code you can also use `print( dir(key) )` to see what fields it has, or `help( key )` to see its `docstring`

Comment: in documentation there is example for monitoring keyboard and it use `except AttributeError:` so it is strange why it use it - and then you can suspect that sometimes it may not give some attribue. Belowe example you can also read `The key parameter passed to callbacks is a pynput.keyboard.Key, for special keys, a pynput.keyboard.KeyCode for normal alphanumeric keys, or just None for unknown keys.` - and if it uses three different objects - `Key, KeyCode, None` - then it may have different attributes and it may need `try/except` or `isinstance()` to work with different objects.